# ¿Como verificar si una cadena ingresada se encuentra dentro de un rango numérico?

Tags: linux, bash, consola

Mi duda es como hago para verificar si el valor ingresado es un valor entero entre 0 y 7. Supongo que puede hacerse, pero no me viene a la mente la idea. Gracias.-

Edición: vi algo como ésto

```
[[ $variable =~ ^?[0-7]$ ]] #en realidad con 9, pero lo modifiqué para mi caso
                            #y no funcionó ya que puse una letra y el script continuó su ejecución.
```

se entiende por donde viene mi consulta? Gracias por su tiempo!

Comment: ¿Ingresado de que forma? ¿estamos hablando de un script `bash` o de otra cosa?

Comment: si, es un `script` en el que solicito un valor, que debe ser únicamente un número entre 0 y 7, ni negativo ni 8 o mayor

Answer (score 3):

Básicamente dos validaciones:

1. Que la cadena ingresada sea solo numeros
2. Que estos números solo estén dentro de un rango

La forma más estándar de resolver ambas situaciones sería:

```
# Solo números
case $number in
   [!0-9]*) echo "Ingrese un numero válido" ;;
esac

# ¿Esta en el rango?
if [ "$number" -ge 0 -a "$number" -le 7 ]; then
  echo "$number entra en un rango valido"
fi
```

En realidad `[ ]`  es un alias para el comando [`test`](http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_man_pages/testh.html), `-ge` -> mayor igual a, `-a` es el y lógico y `le` -> menor igual a. **Importante**: recuerda agregar un espacio luego de `[` y  antes `]`

Sin embargo, si apuntas a Bash, hay formas más "idiomaticas", por ejemplo:

```
# Solo números
[[ $number =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]] || { echo "Ingrese un numero válido"; }
# ¿Esta en el rango?
if ((number >= 0 && number <= 7)); then
  echo "$number entra en un rango valido"
fi
```

En primer lugar usamos el operador incorporado de expresiones regulares de Bash `=~` para verificar solo caracteres numéricos y luego mediante la evaluación de expresiones aritméticas utilizando [`((…))`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Conditional-Constructs.html#Conditional-Constructs)

Por ejemplo:

```
if ((number>= 0 && number<= 7)); then
  echo "$number entra en un rango valido"
fi
```

Algunas consideraciones:

- La evaluación es, únicamente sobre un rango de números enteros, lamentablemente para números de coma flotante hay que hacer algo completamente distinto
- La evaluación [`((…))`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Conditional-Constructs.html#Conditional-Constructs) igual que `"=~` son expresiones particulares de bash por lo que el "shebang" del script debería apuntar al mismo `#!/bin/bash`
- Con este rango no vas a tener problemas, pero recuerda que un número ingresado como `08` es interpretado como un octal y te dará error, por lo que resulta práctico convertirlo base 10 mediante `number="10#$number"`

Un ejemplo de un script que solicita un número dentro del rango solicitado:

```
#!/bin/bash

while :; do
  read -p "Ingrese un número entre 0 y 7: " number
  [[ $number =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]] || { echo "Ingrese un numero válido"; continue; }
  number="10#$number"
  if ((number >= 0 && number <= 7)); then
    echo "Número válido"
    break
  else
    echo "Numero fuera del rango, vuelva a intentarlo"
  fi
done
```

Fuentes:

- [How to check if a number is within a range in shell](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50521798/6836377)
- [Arithmetic expressions](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/arith_expr)
- [brackets](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/32211/235922)

Comment: Muchas Gracias, Probaré a ver que resulta, porque como dice la edición de la pregunta, ese código no da error al ingresar una letra

Comment: @Vizz3rdriX, son dos validaciones distintas, 1) que sea numérico y 2) que esté dentro del rango. Revisa el script de ejemplo de mi respuesta que válida ambas situaciones, aunque originalmente la respuesta se orienta a responder únicamente el tema del rango numérico. Trataré de editarla acorde a tu nueva edición.

Comment: Hay algo que no entiendo, ese `while :;` no lo entiendo, en si el `:;` que función cumple o como funciona?

Comment: El `while :; do` es una forma de indicar un loop infinito. Los `:` en bash es "no hacer nada y retornar 0"

Answer (score 0):

Esta web te ayudará a comprender y a realizar lo que estas buscando de forma muy sencilla.

[Expresiones Regulares Online](https://regex101.com/)

Aunque con este patrón ya tendrías lo deseado `^[0-7]$`. Espero que te sirva de ayuda.